# Create pretty url's with GET variables

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At this moment I have a situation in which pretty url's are rewritten so that everything goes by the index.php, while maintaining the `$_GET` variables. The htaccess looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?p=$1&projectid=$2&sub=$3&type=$4
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?p=$1&projectid=$2&sub=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?p=$1&projectid=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

This works fine. However, I want it to work the other way around as well. If someone goes to http://www.example.com/index.php?p=page&projectid=123 that they will be redirected to http://www.example.com/page/123.

Is this possible, and if so, how? All I've managed so far is creating a redirect loop.

For those interested, the redirect loop I created looks as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://www.example.com/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: look into existing router solutions (ZF, SF etc.).

Comment: @fejese: Could you give me a link of where I can read into that? I've never heard of that before.

Comment: For example http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to work the other way around as well. If someone goes to `http://www.example.com/index.php?p=page&projectid=123` that they will be redirected to `http://www.example.com/page/123`

Yes it indeed possible but you will need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable for that.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+)&projectid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]
```

You can build similar rule for other URLs as well.